# Join a table with 2 other tables which may or maynot have related rows

Tags: mysql, join

I have 3 tables ie:

1. `products ( id, title)`
2. `Stock_in ( product_id, qty, date)`
3. `stock_out (product_id, qty, date)`

I want to use joins to fetch a list of stock movement of each product.

I tried joining all 3 tables using basic joins,  but the problem with my query is that it returns rows for the products which have both in and out movements.

This is the best I could do, all other queries I tried were worst

```
SELECT  c.title, si.qty, so.qty, si.date  , so.date
   FROM `products` c, stock_in si , stock_out so
   where (c.id LIKE si.code OR c.id LIKE so.code)
   group by c.code_id
```

The expected result is to show rows for each product with a stock movement for each date either the in and out in the same row or 2 different rows.

Maybe join all 3 tables is a wrong approach, and I should run 2 queries each for stock in data and stock out data and then later in backend merge the rows? Will that be optimized?

Comment: A perusal of any basic, introductory book or tutorial will pay dividends

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have not got a aggregation function, so you should not use group by but distinct. Also, you should use explicit join syntax based on left join if the rows between the table could not match.

```
    SELECT distinct c.title
        , si.qty
        , so.qty
        , si.date  
        , so.date   
    FROM `products` c
    LEFT JOIN stock_in si  ON  c.id =  si.code
    LEFT JOIN stock_out so OON c.id = so.code
```